# C++ GRPC ClientAsyncReaderWriter: how to check if data is available for read?

Tags: c++, grpc

I have bidirectional streaming async grpc client that use ClientAsyncReaderWriter for communication with server. RPC code looks like:

```
rpc Process (stream Request) returns (stream Response)
```

For simplicity Request and Response are bytes arrays (`byte[]`). I send several chunks of data to server, and when server accumulate enough data, server process this data and send back the response and continue accumulating data for next responses. After several responses, the server send final response and close connection.

For async client I using `CompletionQueue`. Code looks like:

```
...
CompletionQueue cq;
std::unique_ptr<Stub> stub;
grpc::ClientContext context;
std::unique_ptr<grpc::ClientAsyncReaderWriter<Request,Response>> responder = stub->AsyncProcess(&context, &cq, handler);

// thread for completition queue
std::thread t(
    []{
        void *handler = nullptr;
        bool ok = false;
        while (cq_.Next(&handler, &ok)) {
            if (can_read) {
                // how do you know that it is read data available
                // Do read
            } else {
                // do write
                ...
                Request request = prepare_request();
                responder_->Write(request, handler);
            }
        }
    }
);

...
// wait
```

What is the proper way to async reading? Can I try to read if it no data available? Is it blocking call?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [examples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/cpp) or [test](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/test) folder of the gRPC repository? There might be useful code examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Sequencing Read() calls

> Can I try to read if it no data available?

Yep, and it's going to be case more often than not. `Read()` will do nothing until data is available, and only then put its passed tag into the completion queue. (see below for details)

> Is it blocking call?

Nope. `Read()` and `Write()` return immediately. However, you can only have one of each in flight at any given moment. If you try to send a second one before the previous has completed, it (the second one) will fail.

> What is the proper way to async reading?

Each time a `Read()` is done, start a new one. For that, you need to be able to tell when a `Read()` is done. This is where tags come in!

When you call `Read(&msg, tag)`, or `Write(request, tag)`,you are telling grpc to put `tag` in the completion queue associated with that responder once that operation has completed. grpc doesn't care what the tag is, it just hands it off.

So the general strategy you will want to go for is:

- As soon as you are ready to start receiving messages:

  - call `responder->Read()` once with some tag that you will recognize as a "read done".
- Whenever `cq_.Next()` gives you back that tag, and `ok == true`:

  - consume the message
  - Queue up a new `responder->Read()` with that same tag.

Obviously, you'll also want to do something similar for your calls to `Write()`.

But since you still want to be able to lookup the handler instance from a given tag, you'll need a way to pack a reference to the handler as well as information about which operation is being finished in a single tag.

#### Completion queues

*Lookup the handler instance from a given tag*? Why?

The true *raison d'être* of completion queues is unfortunately not evident from the examples. They allow multiple asynchronous rpcs to share the same thread. Unless your application only ever makes a single rpc call, the handling thread should not be associated with a specific responder. Instead, that thread should be a general-purpose worker that dispatches events to the correct handler based on the content of the tag.

The official examples tend to do that by using pointer to the handler object as the tag. That works when there's a specific sequence of events to expect since you can easily predict what a handler is reacting to. You often can't do that with async bidirectional streams, since any given completion event could be a `Read()` or a `Write()` finishing.

#### Example

Here's a general outline of what I personally consider to be a clean way to go about all that:

```
// Base class for async bidir RPCs handlers. 
// This is so that the handling thread is not associated with a specific rpc method.
class RpcHandler {
  // This will be used as the "tag" argument to the various grpc calls.
  struct TagData {
    enum class Type {
      start_done,
      read_done,
      write_done,
      // add more as needed...
    };

    RpcHandler* handler;
    Type evt;
  };

  struct TagSet {
    TagSet(RpcHandler* self)
        : start_done{self, TagData::Type::start_done},
          read_done{self, TagData::Type::read_done},
          write_done{self, TagData::Type::write_done} {}
    TagData start_done;
    TagData read_done;
    TagData write_done;
  };

 public:
  RpcHandler() : tags(this) {}

  virtual ~RpcHandler() = default;

  // The actual tag objects we'll be passing
  TagSet tags;

  virtual void on_ready() = 0;
  virtual void on_recv() = 0;
  virtual void on_write_done() = 0;

  static void handling_thread_main(grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) {
    void* raw_tag = nullptr;
    bool ok = false;

    while (cq->Next(&raw_tag, &ok)) {
      TagData* tag = reinterpret_cast<TagData*>(raw_tag);
      if(!ok) {
        // Handle error
      }
      else {
        switch (tag->evt) {
          case TagData::Type::start_done:
            tag->handler->on_ready();
            break;
          case TagData::Type::read_done:
            tag->handler->on_recv();
            break;
          case TagData::Type::write_done:
            tag->handler->on_write_done();
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

void do_something_with_response(Response const&);

class MyHandler final : public RpcHandler {
 public:
  using responder_ptr =
      std::unique_ptr<grpc::ClientAsyncReaderWriter<Request, Response>>;

  MyHandler(responder_ptr responder) : responder_(std::move(responder)) {
    // This lock is needed because StartCall() can
    // cause the handler thread to access the object.
    std::lock_guard lock(mutex_);

    responder_->StartCall(&tags.start_done);
  }

  ~MyHandler() {
    // TODO: finish/abort the streaming rpc as appropriate.
  }

  void send(const Request& msg) {
    std::lock_guard lock(mutex_);
    if (!sending_) {
      sending_ = true;
      responder_->Write(msg, &tags.write_done);
    } else {
      // TODO: add some form of synchronous wait, or outright failure
      // if the queue starts to get too big.
      queued_msgs_.push(msg);
    }
  }

 private:
  // When the rpc is ready, queue the first read
  void on_ready() override {
    std::lock_guard l(mutex_);  // To synchronize with the constructor
    responder_->Read(&incoming_, &tags.read_done);
  };

  // When a message arrives, use it, and start reading the next one
  void on_recv() override {
    // incoming_ never leaves the handling thread, so no need to lock

    // ------ If handling is cheap and stays in the handling thread.
    do_something_with_response(incoming_);
    responder_->Read(&incoming_, &tags.read_done);

    // ------ If responses is expensive or involves another thread.
    // Response msg = std::move(incoming_); 
    // responder_->Read(&incoming_, &tags.read_done); 
    // do_something_with_response(msg);
  };

  // When has been sent, send the next one is there is any
  void on_write_done() override {
    std::lock_guard lock(mutex_);
    if (!queued_msgs_.empty()) {
      responder_->Write(queued_msgs_.front(), &tags.write_done);
      queued_msgs_.pop();
    } else {
      sending_ = false;
    }
  };

  responder_ptr responder_;

  // Only ever touched by the handler thread post-construction.
  Response incoming_;

  bool sending_ = false;
  std::queue<Request> queued_msgs_;

  std::mutex mutex_;  // grpc might be thread-safe, MyHandler isn't...
};

int main() {
  // Start the thread as soon as you have a completion queue.
  auto cq = std::make_unique<grpc::CompletionQueue>();
  std::thread t(RpcHandler::handling_thread_main, cq.get());

  // Multiple concurent RPCs sharing the same handling thread:
  MyHandler handler1(serviceA->MethodA(&context, cq.get()));
  MyHandler handler2(serviceA->MethodA(&context, cq.get()));
  MyHandlerB handler3(serviceA->MethodB(&context, cq.get()));
  MyHandlerC handler4(serviceB->MethodC(&context, cq.get()));
}
```

If you have a keen eye, you will notice that the code above stores a bunch (1 per event type) of redundant `this` pointers in the handler. It's generally not a big deal, but it is possible to do without them via multiple inheritance and downcasting, but that's starting to be somewhat beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you @Frank for answer. This concept is hard to understand :) Unfortunately there is not officialy example of streaming interface. Google speech api example was good for me https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-samples/blob/main/speech/api/streaming_transcribe_singlethread.cc

Comment: Thanks so much.  I was banging my head against a wall trying to figure out how to get bidi streaming to work.  This example + the audio streaming example got me there.

Comment: One more useful example https://grpc.io/docs/guides/performance/